# setOnFocusChangeListener problema com edittext sem preencher

Tags: java, android, android-studio, android-activity, android-adapter

alguem poderia me ajudar por favor.

Eu estou com um problema, eu fiz um setonfocus no meu app, para ele calcular e mostrar o resultado assim que o usuario clicar fora do edittext, porem se o usuario nao digitar nada, o app fecha e da erro no Integer.parserint alguem aqui ja passou por isso e poderia me ajudar por favor. Eu queria que se o usuario nao digitar nada, o app continuasse.

```
precoEdittext.setOnFocusChangeListener(new View.OnFocusChangeListener() {
            @Override
            public void onFocusChange(View v, boolean hasFocus) {
                if (!hasFocus && precoEdittext.getText().toString() != null){
                    String tempEdittextqtd = qtdEdittext.getText().toString();
                    int qtdEdittextI = 0;
                    qtdEdittextI = Integer.parseInt(tempEdittextqtd);
                    String  tempEdittextprec = precoEdittext.getText( ).toString( );
                    int precoEdittextI = 0 ;
                    precoEdittextI = Integer.parseInt( tempEdittextprec );
                    resulEdittext = qtdEdittextI * precoEdittextI;
                    totalEdittext.setText(String.valueOf("R$"+resulEdittext));
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"TOTAL EDITTEXT "+totalEdittext.getText().toString(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
            }
        });
```

Answer (score 0):

O problema é que o conteúdo do `EditText` como string vazia não pode ser convertido para um inteiro. Uma alternativa que você utilizar é atribuir o valor zero caso o texto esteja vazio.

```java
int qtdEdittextI = 0;
int precoEdittextI = 0 ;
try {
    String tempEdittextqtd = qtdEdittext.getText().toString();
    qtdEdittextI = Integer.parseInt(tempEdittextqtd);
} catch (Exception e) { 
    qtdEdittext.setText("0")
}
try {
    String tempEdittextprec = precoEdittext.getText( ).toString( );
    precoEdittextI = Integer.parseInt( tempEdittextprec );
} catch (Exception e) { 
    precoEdittext.setText("0")
}
```